# Instantiate an object with a property of custom type using dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, constructor, inner-classes

I have a few other nested classes in my design and I am instantiating an object using a dictionary which later itself is converted from a JSON file. In the JSON file I have nested relationship, e.g., `Employee` and list of `Education` (1 to many). For simplicity, I bring the following example to present my question:

I have the following classes defined:

```
def ensure_type(value, types):
    if (isinstance(value, list)): # when value is a list
        for element in value:
            ensure_type(element, types)
        return value
    elif isinstance(value, dict):
        for k,v in value.items(): # when value is a dict
            ensure_type(v, types)
        return value
    elif isinstance(value, types):
        return value
    else:
        raise TypeError('Value {value} is {value_type}, but should be {types}!'.format(value=value, value_type=type(value), types=types))


class Education:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        print('im here')
        self.school_name = ensure_type(kwargs.get('school_name'), str)


class Employee:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.fname = ensure_type(kwargs.get('fname'), str)
        self.education = ensure_type(kwargs.get('education'), Education)
```

where I validate the `type` using my custom function `ensure_type`.

I would like to instantiate an employee using the following:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    emp_dict = {'fname': 'Bob', 'education': [{'school_name':'foo'}, {'school_name':'bar'}]}
    
    employee1 = Employee(**emp_dict)
```

when I try the approach above, I get the following error:

```
  File "test.py", line 32, in <module>
    employee1 = Employee(**emp_dict)
  File "test.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.education = ensure_type(kwargs.get('education'), Education)
  File "test.py", line 5, in ensure_type
    ensure_type(element, types)
  File "test.py", line 9, in ensure_type
    ensure_type(v, types)
  File "test.py", line 14, in ensure_type
    raise TypeError('Value {value} is {value_type}, but should be {types}!'.format(value=value, value_type=type(value), types=types))
TypeError: Value foo is <class 'str'>, but should be <class '__main__.Education'>!
```

When I update the Employee class with following line:

```
self.education = Education(kwargs.get('education'))
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testt.py", line 32, in <module>
    employee1 = Employee(**emp_dict)
  File "testt.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.education = Education(kwargs.get('education'))
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I would appreciate if you could kindly guide me on how to resolve this issue.

**NOTE:**
Initially I defined my constructor similar to the following:

```
    def __init__(self, iterable=(), **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(iterable, **kwargs)
```

it's a very powerful and flexible approach, but *I need to have some (or all) properties to be `required`* i.e., user must provide their values when instantiating an `Employee` object. That's why I chose not to pursue the approach above.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the comment. I edited the post and make it a runnable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following code illustrates how to avoid the error. It modifies the `ensure_type()` function so if an element of a list isn't the proper type (`kind`), it performs a further check to see if the element is a `dict` that can be used to construct and instance of the type. It also replaces the dictionary with the instance created, but whether you want this to happen is unclear.

If you want something similar to happen for dictionaries, you'll need to do something very similar to each of the values in one.

**Note:** As written, the code requires at least Python 3.8 due to its use of the `:=` [assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) (aka “the walrus operator”).

```
def ensure_type(value, kind):

    if (isinstance(value, list)):
        # Make sure elements of list are instances of kind or can be
        # used to create an instance of one.
        for i, element in enumerate(value):
            try:
                ensure_type(element, kind)
            except TypeError:
                # Unless element is dict that can be used to create an
                # instance of kind.
                if(not isinstance(element, dict) or
                   not isinstance(inst := kind(**element), kind)):
                    raise
                else:
                    value[i] = inst  # Replace element with instance (OPTIONAL)
        return value

    elif isinstance(value, dict):
        for k,v in value.items():
            # Make sure the value of each item in dict is an instance of kind.
            ensure_type(v, kind)
        return value

    elif isinstance(value, kind):
        return value

    else:
        raise TypeError(
            'Value {value} is {value_type}, but should be {kind}!'.format(
                value=value, value_type=type(value), kind=kind))


class Printable:  # Added to print test results.
    """ Class which can print a represenation of itself. """
    def __repr__(self):
        typename = type(self).__name__
        args = ', '.join("%s=%r" % item for item in vars(self).items())
        return '{typename}({args})'.format(typename=typename, args=args)


class Education(Printable):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
#        print("I'm here")
        self.school_name = ensure_type(kwargs.get('school_name'), str)


class Employee(Printable):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.fname = ensure_type(kwargs.get('fname'), str)
        self.education = ensure_type(kwargs.get('education'), Education)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    emp_dict = {'fname': 'Bob',
                'education': [{'school_name':'foo'}, {'school_name':'bar'}]}
    employee1 = Employee(**emp_dict)
    print(employee1)
```

Output:

```
Employee(fname='Bob', education=[Education(school_name='foo'), Education(school_name='bar')])
```